# Translation pt_BR

Tags: language

Where can I find the translation for pt_BR?
I logged in and signed up to Transifex, but couldn't download the language.
I also did not find where and how to install the translation.
Can anyone inform me?

Answer (score 2):

There are some instructions here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/i18n+Administrator%27s+Guide%3A+Using+CiviCRM+in+your+own+language. The download is in the dropdown at https://civicrm.org/download as a bundle that includes all the languages.

Transifex is for entering the translations.